# Install Windows 7 from disk

Tags: windows-7

I have Windows 7 OEM disk and I want to install it and wipe my vista installation.

Should I just insert the disk into the cd drive whilst the PC is running and see if the options come up, or do I need to change the boot sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the boot sequence to boot from DVD first. OEM CDs don't have an upgrade option, so the install cannot be launched from inside of Windows. Upgrade installs are the only ones that can be started from inside of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the Windows 7 installer does have the feature to create its own bootloader and have that read the CD, same as with Windows XP. Not sure, though.

Comment: And dang for keyboard mashing (29 second difference).